# Python 3 : Storing Data without loading it into memory

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I am currently building a flask app that will have lots of data that I think I cannot load into memory. I have searched many places, and have found the SQL seems to be a good solution. Sadly I cannot use SQL for this project due to some limitations of SQL.

My project consists many entries of

```
database[lookupkey1][lookupkey2]...and more lookup keys
```

My current plan is to override __getitem__ and __setitem__ and __delitem__ and replace them with calls to the database. Is their any kind of database that can store large amounts of maps/dictionaries like

```
{"spam":{"bar":["foo","test"],"foo":["bar"]}}
```

I am also currently using JSON to save data, so it would be appreciated if the database had a easy way to migrate my current database.

Sorry that I'm not very good at writing stack overflow questions.

Comment: I'd be quite surprised if SQL has enough limitations to seriously hamper your project. Which implementation of SQL are you using that's not meeting your needs?

Comment: SQLite for Python 3, also I'm pretty bad at SQL anyway too so I'm taking some tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

Most document-oriented DBs like MongoDB would allow you to save data as nested dict-list-like objects and query them using their keys and indexes.

P.S. Accessing such a DB through a Python's dict accessors is a bad idea as it would produce a redundant DB query for each step which is highly ineffective and may lead to performance problems. Try looking at ORM for a DB you choose as most ORMs would allow you to access document-oriented DB's data in a way similar to accessing dicts and lists.

Comment: I'm going to try your solution, and thanks for the tip about dict accessors!